# Computation Tree Logic and Linear Time Logic

Tags: logic

I need to learn the proof of why the following statement holds, I would be really grateful if you could help me understand:
$¬(f ~\mathcal R ~ g) ≡ ((¬f) ~\mathcal U~ (¬g))$

$\mathcal R$: Release

$\mathcal U$: Until

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos!

Answer (score 0):

$f~\mathcal R~g$:$f$ releases $g$; $g$ must remain true up to and including the point $f$ becomes true.

$f~\mathcal U~g$: $f$ until $g$; $f$ has to remain true at least until $g$ becomes true.

So that not $f$ releases $g$, entails that it is that $f$ remains false until $g$ becomes false.

And $\lnot f$ until $\lnot g$, entails that it is not that $g$ remains true up till $f$ becomes true.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your point, would you please elaborate?